# how to access and update class variable of singleton class in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

the declaration is as follows:- (CalendarSetting.h)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalendarSetting : NSObject

@property(class,strong,nonatomic)NSDate *currentDate;

@end
```

//implementation made is:-(CalendarSetting.m)

```
+(void)set_member_var:(NSDate *)fordate
{

[CalendarSetting setCurrentDate:fordate];

}

+(void)setCurrentDate:(NSDate *)currentDate
{
    CalendarSetting.currentDate=currentDate;
    return;
}
```

Now this flow is causing a recursive call of setCurrentDate also how can i read value of currentDate in same .m file or any other class?

Comment: Your class doesn't look like singleton to me

Comment: In the setter you are calling the setter which is why the recursive behaviour. Access the backing ivar directly in the setter like _currentDate = currentDate;

Comment: i have over ridden sharedInstance in .m . What else I have to do make it Singleton.

Comment: _currentDate is not accepting :(

Comment: Ahh.. why a class variable? Make it an ivar, if it really is a singleton then there will only be one anyway.

Comment: Singleton only have 1 instance, you can change it's property value by `[CalendarSetting sharedInstance].currentDate = currentDate`

Comment: ok..i will try ivar...till then...can anyone please tell me the usability of @synchronise in singleton

Comment: @Tj3n for this i have to make currentDate as instance variable whose value will be reinitialized to null on each instance creation.

Comment: Please read a tutorial about creating a shared instance ("singleton") in Objective-C.

Comment: @log But if it is a singleton there will only be one instance.

Comment: thanks all of you for your help I will try again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **@implementation** you need to declare a backing store for the class property -

```
@implementation CalendarSetting
static NSDate *_currentDate = nil;
// continue for other class vars...
```

And for your **accessors** *assign* or *return* the **static** **variable**.

example setter -

```
+(void)setCurrentDate:(NSDate *)currentDate {
      _currentDate = [currentDate copy];
}
```

example getter for reading currentDate -

```
+(NSDate*)currentDate {
     return _currentDate; // can return nil
}
```